# Авіаційна (aviation)/планерна (gliding) термінологія

Tags: терміни, resource-request, словники

Добридень,

шукаю авіаційну/планерну тремінологію (з англійської на українську). Можливо підкажете надійні джерела де можна її подивитися або товариства, які дотичні до розробки термінології.

Answer (score 4):

[*Науково теоретичний журнал*](//web.archive.org/web/20200322120907/http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/new_books/Documents/ukrainska-mova-3-2014.pdf) [3 (51), 2014 р.] має статтю *Українська авіаційна термінологія у лексикографічному опрацюванні* [на 93 с., [Людмила Халіновська](//www.nas.gov.ua/UA/PersonalSite/Pages/default.aspx?PersonID=0000018977)]. Там згадані такі вузькоспеціялізовані матеріяли:

- [Німецький та український летунський словник /
  Deutsches und ukrainisches Fliegewörter buch](//diasporiana.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/books/3727/file.pdf) (близько 20 000 слів)
  (видавництво Бернард і Грефе, Берлін, 1939 р.), [Іван Ільницький-Занкович](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD).
- Летунський словник (дискусійний матеріал) Летунський український клюб (ЛУК). —
  Нью-Йорк, 1974. — грудень, ч. І
- Український летунський словник. Проєкт. Летунський Український Клюб (ЛУК). — Торонто, [б. д.].
- Російсько-українсько-англійська авіаційна термінологія. Д. Г. Бабейчук (близько 4000 українських, російських та англійських термінів), 1997 р.
- Російсько-український авіаційний словник (8 тисяч термінів) за редакцією Г. О. Кривова, 1997 р.
- Російсько-український словник з авіаційної та ракетнокосмічної техніки (близько 40 тисяч термінів і терміносполучень, 1997 р.) за ред. Д. Х. Баранника і В. Ф. Пріснякова
- Російсько-український словник авіаційних термінів (близько 80 тисяч лексичних одиниць, 2004 р.) у двох томах за редакцією В. П. Бабака
- Тлумачний словник авіаційних термінів (укл. Л. Ф. Верхулевська, С. С. Кіраль, М. В. Луцюк, Л. Г. Скуратівська та Н. Ю. Ясакова за загальною редакцією М. С. Кулика), близько 1200 термінів і термінологічних словосполучень

Тож… як можна поме̂тити, щонайменше до 2014 року, останні словники переважно з напрямком до московскої мови, пак Халіновська дале̂ наводе суто москівські словники, тому *здаєть ся*, що якщо з анґлійським перекладом, то будуть діяпоріянські, котрих знаходити мене̂ не удаєть ся. Це особливо це̂каво, бо знаходю наприклад таке:

- [Англійсько-український словник авіаційних термінів](https://archive.org/details/anhlukrsl3) [близько 24 000 термінів та словосполучень] / уклад. Р. О. Гільченко. - Фастів : КуПол, 2009. - 280 с.

З нове̂ших:

- Авіаційно-технічний тлумачний словник-довідник з цивільної авіації, А. В. Скрипець

Також можна звернути увагу на катеґорію [*Авіаційні терміни*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B8) на Вікіпедії.